# How to work with operating system restriction on maximum number of processes in a recursive multiprocessing function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, operating-system, multiprocessing

I am having some problems understanding what i going on with the processes in the following code I wrote as a simplification of some other script I am writing to get to grips with multiprocessing:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
from random import randint
from os import getpid



def f(i, process_id, parent_process_message_queue):

    print (i,process_id, getpid())
    time.sleep(randint(0,10)/100)

    child_processes = []
    child_process_message_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    if randint(0,10) > 4:
        child_processes.append(multiprocessing.Process(target = f, args = (i+1, 0, child_process_message_queue)))
        child_processes[-1].start()
        child_processes.append(multiprocessing.Process(target = f, args = (i+1, 1, child_process_message_queue)))
        child_processes[-1].start()

    while not child_process_message_queue.empty():
        child_id = child_process_message_queue.get()
        child_processes[child_id].join()
    parent_process_message_queue.put(process_id)


child_process_message_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

p = multiprocessing.Process(target = f, args = (0, 0, child_process_message_queue))
p.start()

while not child_process_message_queue.empty():
    child_id = child_process_message_queue.get()
    child_processes[child_id].join()

p.join()
```

When not too many recursive calls happen (because of the random element) then this code seems to work as intended.

Output of a successful run looks like this:

```
0 0 57756
1 0 57757
1 1 57758
2 0 57759
2 1 57760
3 0 57761
3 1 57762
3 0 57763
3 1 57764
4 0 57765
4 1 57766
4 0 57767
4 1 57768
5 0 57769
5 1 57770
```

However when too many recursive calls are being made, things get strange; things like this appear, including some error message:

```
Process Process-1:2:1:2:1:2:2:2:2:1:1:1:1:1:1:1:1:2:2:2:2:2:2:1:1:1:2:2:1:1:1:1:2:1:2:1:
Process Process-1:2:1:2:1:2:2:2:2:1:1:1:1:1:1:1:2:2:2:1:2:2:2:1:2:2:2:1:2:2:2:1:1:2:2:2:1:1:1:1:2:
Process Process-1:2:1:2:1:2:2:2:2:1:1:1:1:1:1:1:1:2:2:2:2:2:2:2:2:2:2:2:2:2:1:2:2:2:1:2:2:2:1:2:
Process Process-1:2:1:2:1:2:2:2:2:1:1:1:1:1:1:1:1:2:2:2:1:2:2:2:1:2:1:2:2:1:1:2:2:1:2:2:1:2:1:1:2:1:1:
Process Process-1:2:1:2:2:2:2:1:2:2:2:1:1:1:2:1:2:2:1:2:2:1:1:2:1:1:1:2:1:1:2:2:1:1:1:1:1:1:1:1:2:1:1:2:2:2:2:2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "queuetest2.py", line 18, in f
    child_processes[-1].start()
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 105, in start
[...]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    BlockingIOError: [Errno 35] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I searched for that error (BlockingIOError: [Errno 35]) and apparently this behaviour is caused by the scrip trying to create more processes than allowed by the OS. Now I wonder: What os the best way of dealing with this? I don't imagine recursive functions that use multiprocessing are a bad idea per se, are they? A solution might need to check whether the process cap has been reached yet, and if so continue the recursion in the same thread, and if not, keep spawning new processes, but is that a sound approach?

Answer (score 1):

Even when the number of recursive calls is low, your approach is quite detrimental for the performance.

Generally, on CPU bound types of jobs it's better to keep a process/CPU ratio of 1. For IO bounds jobs instead, threading is a better approach. For hybrid jobs it gets a bit more complicated and only testing the workload can give a concrete answers.

Independently from the workload, the developer always wants to be in control over the amount of processes/threads the application is going to create. To achieve that, the simplest design pattern to be used is the [Pool of Workers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool).

Python library offers two different implementations: [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) and [`concurrent.futures.Executor`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/concurrent.futures.html?highlight=concurrent%20futures#executor-objects).